# Linux Mailx is creating a dead.letter and not sending email

Tags: linux, rhel, sendmail, mailx

I am having issues with sending emails from my Redhat6 linux server. Each type of mailing command sendmail/mailx creates a dead.letter in the users home directory.

Examples of how I am sending things:

```
mailx -s "backup complete - cron bla" test@example.com

echo "Subject: hello" | sendmail test@example.com
```

(In a bash script)

```
page /usr/log/example.log | mailx -s "example - cron example" test@example.com
```

> Dead Letter Message:
>
> Date: Wed, 9 Jan 2019 07:20:32 -0500 From: bob Message-Id:
>   <201901091220.x09CKWMG009291@myserver> Subject: hello

Comment: What is result of using `date | mailx -v -s TEST test@example.com` (I'm particularly interested in what the MTA splits out as a consequence of the `-v` flag). Also, what is in the mail logs (see `/var/log`)?

Comment: Your second example is wrong. If you're going to pipe to `sendmail` you should have a properly formatted email.

Comment: [tstog@serveraddress ~]$ date | mailx -v -s TEST email@example.com
email@example.com... Connecting to [IPAddress] via relay...
220 ServerAddressName ESMTP Sendmail 8.14.4/8.14.4; Wed, 9 Jan 2019 09:26:34 -0500
>>> EHLO ServerAddressName
250-ServerAddressName Hello localhost [IPAddress], pleased to meet you
250 ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES
>>> MAIL From:<tstog@serveraddress>
550 5.0.0 Access denied
/home/tstog/dead.letter... Saved message in /home/tstog/dead.letter
Closing connection to [IPAddress]
>>> QUIT
221 2.0.0 ServerAddressName closing connection

Comment: I just put a random email in this example. Also in the above I replaced some server names and ipaddress for security reasons.

Comment: The second example echo "Subject: hello" | sendmail test@example.com works find with a valid email. That is just a random address I put so I don't put my own email address.

Comment: Please [edit your question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/493454/edit) to include the information. Putting it in comments makes it almost entirely unreadable, and it's easy to lose valuable updates.

Comment: Ah... no thank you but thank you for the help.. I am in an environment where I don't feel comfortable with sharing my ipaddress and server names. The Access Denied though does give me an idea of where to look. appreciate the help hopefully you do not get upset.

Comment: That's not what I meant. (At least, not yet.) When you're asked for additional information please don't put it here in the comments. [Add it](https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/493454/edit) to your question, ideally as if you'd thought of it in the first place. The idea is to make your question as easy to read and as complete as possible, so that it's easy for others to read it, understand it, and hopefully give you an answer.

Answer (score 1):

The file **dead.letter** is created when the mta fails when it tries to send a mail. Check all the configurations related with the mail server (credentials, mail server...) and also that you can reach the mail server, otherwise you will have that problem.

Comment: Also check your MTA logs to see *why* the message failed to send while you're checking your configs, it'll be useful to see why it actually failed to deliver, and that won't be shared to you in your mailx command.

Comment: I'll take a look. I'll have to do some exploring to find all the config file.